How is the Bitmap Window overlayed on the 2D Glyph Outline Coordinate Space?
I've got a pretty basic FreeType program to render the glyph for the character 'g' and I'm wondering why the glyph is fully visible within the resulting FreeType Bitmap.
Within section 3 of the following FreeType2 documentation it makes it clear that loaded glyphs have their character origin set to (0, 0) and that the bitmap window is overlayed with the lower-left pixel at (0,0). See diagram below:

Hence I'm wondering why my 'g' glyph is fully visible within the bitmap I've rendered. I was expecting something similar to the rightmost coordinate space in the image above.
All the relevant FreeType code is roughly as follows:
FT_Set_Char_Size(face, 0, 16 * 64, 254, 254);
FT_UInt glyph_index = FT_Get_Char_Index(face, 'g');
FT_Load_Glyph(face, glyph_index, FT_LOAD_GLYPH);
FT_Render_Glyph(face->glyph, FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL);

It's almost verbatim from the Tutorial.
I'm using a Bodoni TrueType File. Result:


First, rendering a scalable vector glyph into a bitmap glyph (rasterization) is not the same as rendering a bitmap glyph into a window or pixmap (presentation, aka text rendering).
FT_Render_Glyph

Convert a given glyph image to a bitmap. It does so by inspecting the glyph image format, finding the relevant renderer, and invoking it.

The relevant renderer will do all the measurements necessary to pick the adequate dimensions for the bitmap.
Excerpt from the linked documentation:

For example, the correct way of creating a stand-alone glyph bitmap is as follows:

Get the size of the glyph bitmap.
Create the bitmap with the computed dimensions.
Translate the outline so that its lower left corner matches (0, 0).
Call the rendering function.


All is automagically done by FT_Render_Glyph, you'll always end up with having a complete image of the underlying glyph.
So, basically the documentation targets those who wants to implement their own custom converter/renderer and i think that is not you (if so, then for outline processing see Outline Processing, more specifically FT_Outline_Render).
Of course, if you want to render the converted glyph(s) into a window/pixmap (surface of arbitrary dimensions), then you'd have to consider the metrics of the font/glyph, e.g. the bearings, ascender, descender, advance and so on. Otherwise clipping can/will occur.

I'm not following why you conflate "window" and "pixmap". The doc states in section 2 that bitmap/pixmap are almost synonymous - but pixmaps for pixel bitdepth > 1.
Additionally, the section I linked is about info on "the positioning of the outline in the 2D plane before converting it to a bitmap". So to me, when I read those 4 bullet points you mentioned, the rasterization step occurs when render function is called and the translation must occur beforehand. Which my sample code doesn't perform.
If it's handled automatically, I wish the doc would say so.

VII. FreeType Bitmaps: "The purpose of this section is to present the way FreeType manages bitmaps and pixmaps...", since you do not manage FreeType bitmaps and pixmaps, the documentation is for informational and educational purposes only. The terms i use (window/pixmap) refer to surfaces outside of FreeType (e.g. your own custom target surface). You asked about FreeType's internals, but you don't use them in your code, i wanted to point that out.
